# The Tits classes of simply connected simple real groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a simply connected semisimple group over a perfect field $k$ (at the moment I am interested in the case $k=\mathbb R$).
Then $G$ is an inner form of a quasi-split $k$-group $G_{\rm qs}$:
there exists a quasi-split form $G_{\rm qs}$ of $G$ and a 1-cocycle $c\in Z^1(k,\overline{G}_{\rm qs})$ such that
$G=\,_c G_{\rm qs}$, the inner twist of $G_{\rm qs}$ by the cocycle $c$, where $\overline{G}_{\rm qs}=G_{\rm qs}/Z_{\rm qs}$ and $Z_{\rm qs}=Z(G_{\rm qs})$.
Let $\xi=[c]\in H^1(k,\overline{G}_{\rm qs})$, the cohomology class of the cocycle $c$.
Let
$$\Delta\colon H^1(k,\overline{G}_{\rm qs})\to H^2(k,Z_{\rm qs})$$
denote the connecting map from the cohomology exact sequence
$$H^1(k,Z_{\rm qs})\to H^1(k,G_{\rm qs})\to H^1(k, \overline{G}_{\rm qs})\to H^2(k,Z_{\rm qs})$$
induced by the short exact sequence
$$ 1\to Z_{\rm qs}\to G_{\rm qs}\to \overline{G}_{\rm qs}\to 1.$$
By definition, the  *Tits class of $G$* is
$$t_G=\Delta(\xi)\in H^2(k,Z_{\rm qs}),$$
see The Book of Involutions, (31.7).
Note that $Z_{\rm qs}=Z:=Z(G)$.

> **Question 1.** Is there anywhere in the literature or in the Internet a table of $t_G$ for all simply connected absolutely simple ${\mathbb R}$-groups $G$?

For all connected Dynkin diagram except for ${\mathsf D}_{2m}$ (and also for ${\mathsf D}_{2m}$ when $G_{\rm qs}$ is not split)
we have either $H^2({\mathbb R},Z_{\rm qs})=0$ or $H^2({\mathbb R},Z_{\rm qs})={\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$.
From the cohomology exact sequence we see that $t_G=0$ if and only if $G$ is a *strong inner* form of $G_{\rm qs}$, that is, $\xi$ comes from $H^1({\mathbb R}, G)$.
I have a table of strong inner forms of $G_{\rm qs}$, and so I know when $t_G=0$; for non-strong inner forms we have $t_G\neq 0$, hence $t_G=1+2{\mathbb Z}\in {\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$.

However, for ${\mathsf D}_{2m}$, in the case when $G_{\rm qs}$ is split, namely $G_{\rm qs}\simeq {\bf Spin}(2m,2m)$, we have $H^2({\mathbb R}, Z_{\rm qs})={\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}\times{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$.
I know that $t_G=0$ if and only if $G$ is a strong inner form of $G_{\rm qs}$, that is, if $G\simeq{\bf Spin}(2m+4q, 2m-4q)$,
but I need an explicit formula for the cases  ${\bf Spin}(2m+4q+2, 2m-4q-2)$ and the quaternionic form ${\bf Spin}^*(4m)$.
Thus Question 1 reduces to the following question:

> **Question 2.** What are the Tits classes for the simple ${\mathbb R}$-groups  ${\bf Spin}(2m+4q+2, 2m-4q-2)$ and ${\bf Spin}^*(4m)$ ?

In order to formulate an answer to Question 2, one needs an explicit description of the center of the split ${\mathbb R}$-group ${\bf Spin}(2m,2m)$.
Such a description is given, for example, in [Brian Conrad's cheat sheet](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jstarr/papers/Centers.pdf).

Comment: What is the oldest or most convenient published reference for the explicit description of the center of the split group in terms of co-roots for which you refer to Brian's cheat sheet?  Of course one can just work out the exercise, but for writing a paper it is convenient to be able to refer to something.  Some of it is in section 17 of Springer's *Linear algebraic groups*, 2nd edition. It is also in my paper with Anne Queguiner *Restricting the Rost invariant to the Center* ( http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S1061-0022-08-00993-X ), where $Spin(2m,2m)$ is Example 8.6.

Comment: @Skip: The most convenient published reference? One can find a description of $P^\vee/Q^\vee$ in the book "Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups" by Onishchik and Vinberg, Springer-Verlag 1990. See Table 3 on page 298.

Comment: @Skip: The *oldest* published reference? The book by Onishchik and Vinberg of 1969 ("Seminar on algebraic groups and Lie groups", in Russian, mimeographed notes, 200 copies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** I haven't seen an explicit table in the literature of the Tits classes for simple $R$-groups.

That said, such a table can be constructed from tables in the literature.  Specifically, the Tits class is determined by the Tits algebras corresponding to the minuscule dominant weights by Proposition 7 in my paper *Outer automorphisms of algebraic groups and determining groups by their maximal tori* 
(Michigan Mathematical Journal 61 #2 (2012), 227-237).

These Tits algebras are described for each simple type in general terms for any $k$ in section 27 of *The Book of Involutions*, and their precise values for $k = \mathbb{R}$ are available in several references, for example Tits's *Tabellen zu den einfachen Lie Gruppen und ihren Darstellungen*.

**Question 2:** Victor answered this question in the language of Tits algebras, not the Tits class, so I just translate his answer.  Identify the projections on the two components of $H^2(\mathbb{R}, Z_{qs}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ with the highest weights of the half-spin representations as in section 4.3 of Tits's paper *Représentations linéaires irréductibles d'un groupe réductif sur un corps quelconque*; this agrees with the identification of $Z_{qs}$ with $\mu_2 \times \mu_2$ that you refer to.  For $SO(2m + 4q + 2, 2m - 4q - 2)$, both half-spin representations are quaternionic, so the Tits class is $(1,1)$.  For $SO^*(4m)$, one half-spin representation is quaternionic and the other is real, so the Tits class is $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your second question you can use the fact that the Tits algebras of a group are the same as for its anisotropic kernel ([J. Tits, Représentations linéaires irréductibles d'un groupe réductif sur un corps quelconque, 5.5](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002185725)), and for a quadratic form the Tits algebras are the components of the even Clifford algebra. So for Spin(2m+4q+2,2m-4q-2) the answer is the same as for the compact group Spin(8q+4), and by the Bott periodicity the same as for the compact group Spin(4), that are clearly just two quaternion algebras.